# Telling apart 16 and 8 bit grascale Images in java

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to read .png grayscaleimages and convert the grayvalues to a
`double[][]`array. and i need to map them  to a value between 0 and 1.

Im using a BufferedImage and I have tried to find out the colordepth using `img.getColorModel().getColorSpace().getType()` but that returned the TYPE_5CLR or TYPE_6CLR Generic component color space which did not help.

Currently im reading the values like this:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

        double[][] heightmap= new double[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
        WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();
        for(int i=0;i<heightmap.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<heightmap[0].length;j++)
            {
                heightmap[i][j]=((double) raster.getSample(i,j,0))/65535.0;
            }
        }
```

The 65535 sould be a 256 if its 8bit but i dont know when.

Comment: What type of `ColorModel` do you get? There are multiple subclasses that provide more detailed properties that the default `ColorModel` does.

Comment: @Robert the `img.getColorModel().getClass()` is java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel

Comment: Are you sure `ColorSpace.getType()` don't return 5 or 6? Which really is `TYPE_RGB` and `TYPE_GRAY` respectively? PNGs with 5 or 6 samples per pixels are very uncommon...

Comment: You could probably use `ColorModel.getNormalizedComponents(...)` instead of implementing this conversion yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote in the comments that you could use `ColorModel.getNormalizedComponents(...)`, but as it uses `float` values and is unnecessary complicated, it might just be easier to implement the conversion like this:

```
BufferedImage img;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
} catch (IOException e) {
    return null;
}

double[][] heightmap = new double[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];

WritableRaster raster = img.getRaster();

// Component size should be 8 or 16, yielding maxValue 255 or 65535 respectively
double maxValue = (1 << img.getColorModel().getComponentSize(0)) - 1;

for(int x = 0; x < heightmap.length; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < heightmap[0].length; y++) {
        heightmap[x][y] = raster.getSample(x, y, 0) / maxValue;
    }
}

return heightmap;
```

Note that the above code will work reliable only for grayscale images, but this seems to be your input anyway. The component size is likely to be the same for all color components (`getComponentSize(0)`), but there might be separate samples for R, G and B (and A, if there's an alpha component), and the code will only get the first sample (`getSample(x, y, 0)`).

PS: I renamed your variables `x` and `y` for clarity. Most likely you will get better performance if you swap the dimensions in your height map, and loop over `x` in the inner loop, instead of `y` due to better data locality.

Comment: It is not necessary to cast the value of `raster.getSample(…)` to a double.  That will be done automatically, since it is being divided by a double (`maxValue`).

Comment: @VGR True. I just kept it from the OP, but it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are assuming the image is grayscale, it’s probably easier to call [getRGB](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,int%29) and divide one of its components:

```
heightmap[i][j] = (img.getRGB(j, i) & 0xff) / 255.0;
```

Comment: This is likely slower, and will throw away 8 bits of precision per sample... But yes, it will get the job done if that's of no concern to the OP.

Comment: @haraldK Agreed, it is probably slower.  I don’t know how important performance is here.

Comment: Fair enough. :-)

Comment: If i have 16 bit i dont want to waste the precision i get from that, because they are heightmaps